# Using Spatialite to add features to a layer does nothing in custom plugin but works in QGIS python console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatialite

### Context

I am developing a QGIS plugin which among other things can save digitized features to existing vector layers in a Spatialite database. I am using the utility class below, to help with retrieving and inserting features.

```
from qgis.utils import spatialite_connect

class SSDM():

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def connected(func):
        ''' This decorator makes sure connections are opened
            before running func and closed after running func.
        '''
        def handler(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with spatialite_connect(self.path) as con:
                self._con = con
                retVal = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            return retVal
        return handler

    @connected
    def addFeature(self, layer, fields, geometry=None):
        filtered = dict((k,v) for k,v in fields.items() if bool(v))
        props = [s.lower() for s in filtered.keys()]
        vals = filtered.values()
        properties = ", ".join(props)
        values = "?, ".join(["",]*(len(vals)+1))[:-2]
        srid = self.getLayerSRID(layer)
        statement = "INSERT INTO %s(%s, shape) VALUES(%s, GeomFromText(?, %s))" % (layer, properties, values, srid)
        cur = self._con.cursor()
        cur.execute(statement, (*vals, geometry))

    @connected
    def getLayerSRID(self, layer):
        cur = self._con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT srid FROM vector_layers WHERE table_name=?", (layer,))
        return cur.fetchone()[0]
```

### To use it:

```
ssdm = SSDM(path_to_sqlite_file)

fields = {"id": 1}
geometry = 'MultiLineStringZM ((31.73134211549897543 33.50656579852068973 0 0, 31.73292725366940914 33.5060147109505948 0 0))'

ssdm.addFeature("vector_layer_name", fields, geometry)
```

### The problem

Oddly enough, when copy pasting this code in the QGIS Python Console, my vector layer is updated with the expected geometry, and with the correct fields in the attribute table.

When running this in my plugin context though, nothing happens. I don't even receive error messages.

Note that the function `SSDM.getLayerSRID` works in both locations (I have checked via remote debugging).